# How to compare two GAMs fit to two different datasets?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-additive-model

Say that I have two logistic GAMs fit on two different datasets that have exactly the same types of predictors (i.e., the same columns, although they could be distributionally different), and I have estimates of $f(x_i)$ from GAM #1 on dataset 1 and estimates of $g(x_i)$ from GAM #2 on dataset 2.

Does there exist a test of some kind that would help answer the question of whether the estimated $f(x_i)$ follow roughly the same shape of the estimated $g(x_i)$ for each $x_i$? All the $x_i$ are continuous, not dichotomous or categorical.

If not, I'd be okay with some kind of visual or heuristic approach, e.g. scaling the $x_i$ to $[-1,1]$ or something and then plotting $f(x_i) - g(x_i)$ to see how closely they coincide, but I'm not sure if this is entirely kosher from a methodological perspective.

Comment: It might be better to fit a single model to all the data, but estimating $f(x_i)$ and $g(x_i)$ via a smooth-factor interaction (`by` variable smooth) using an factor to differentiate between data set 1 and data set 2. Can you explain a little more about the problem you have and why you need two separate models?